# notification on background firebase show dialog when apps open

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-dialog, android-background

Sorry for my title, but let me explain this.
I use firebase cloud messaging on my apps. Now, I need run the apps then show the dialog contain notification body and title when **the apps not running or in background**, after I touch the notification.

For default FCM  is when the apps not running/in background, I touch the notification then apps running/go to foreground.

Can anyone guide me to handle it?

Comment: you will get notification data in a bundle in your launching activity when notification is clicked, so get the data from bundle in launcher activity and use appropriately.

Comment: @AkshayBhat, can u explain more detail, sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Handle notification messages in a backgrounded app**
>
> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> This includes messages that contain **both notification and data payload** (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and **the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity**.
>
> When you send a notification message with a data payload (notification and data) and the app is in the background you can retrieve the data from the extras of the intent that is launched as a result of the user tapping on the notification.

From the [FCM sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MainActivity.java#L47) which launches the MainActivity when the notification is tapped:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
        Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

 In `onMessageRecieved(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` method use `remoteMessage.getData()` to get the data which is sent by server which returns a `Map<String,String>`.
Now create an Intent and specify a class to launch on click of notification and in this intent put your notification data. Like :

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("notification_data", data.getData());
```

Now pass this intent to a pendingIntent when you show a notification.

And when MainActivity.class is launched on click of notification just get the data like this :

```
Map<String,String> notificationDataMap 
      = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("notification_data");
```

So from map you can get the data.

Comment: What I need to take the 'title' and 'body' of the notification? Cause I need to show on a dialog the title & body notification.

Comment: Thanks for you info sir. You save my day :D